# generics in method, c#

Tags: c#, generics

This is my first question so be gentle :)

I want to be able to use method for generic types which will return me object for later use. I have tried the code below but it's not complete.

I need this to call like this: `City city = GetDataById(Id);` Of course instead of city I need generic use.
Thanks and regards.

```
private T GetDataById(Guid Id)
        {
            T obj;
            using (ISession session = Session.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    obj = session.Get<T>(Id);
                    tx.Commit();                    
                }    
                 return obj;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never define T.  You... need to.

```
private T GetDataById<T>(Guid Id) { /* ... */ }
```

And...

```
City city = GetDataById(Id);
```

You'll never be able to call it like that because the type argument cannot be inferred.  You will need to supply it, i.e.,

```
City city = GetDataById<City>(Id);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that you want:

```
    private T GetDataById<T>(Guid Id)
    {
        T obj;
        using (ISession session = Session.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                obj = session.Get<T>(Id);
                tx.Commit();
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

then call it as:

```
        City city = GetDataById<City>(Id);
```